# How do I use the Python modules in webports/naclports with the Python interpreter Chrome app?

Tags: python, numpy, google-nativeclient, ppapi

Webports has projects in the ports directory for Python and several Python modules, including NumPy. The "python" port compiles a Chrome app that runs the Python interpreter in a console window. I'd like to be able to use modules that include native code, like NumPy, in that interpreter.

Here's what I've tried:

- `make numpy` followed by `make python` (in hopes that the Python build process sees that I've already built NumPy and includes it), which doesn't seem to change anything
- Building the python-static package, which fails with a gigantic error message that ends with `libppapi_simple_cpp.a: error: undefined reference to 'PSUserMainGet'`
- Copying `out/build/numpy/numpy-1.8.0/numpy/` into the `site-packages` folder in `pydata.tar` in the Python app. `import numpy` fails with an error message telling me not to import NumPy from its source directory.
- Copying `out/build/numpy/numpy-1.8.0/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/` (which appears to have compiled .so files in it) into the `site-packages` folder in `pydata.tar`. `import numpy` fails with this traceback:

  ```
  >>> import numpy
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
      from . import add_newdocs
    File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
      from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
    File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
      from .type_check import *
    File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
      import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
    File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
      from . import multiarray
  ImportError: cannot import name multiarray
  ```

I'm using the PNaCL toolchain version `pepper_47` inside a Docker container to build the packages, and I'm running the Python app on Chrome 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit) on Xubuntu.

Comment: I'm also getting the "undefined reference to PSUserMainGet" error trying to build the static python port (with pepper_46). Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw `python` port doesn't catch it, but the numpy port was designed to be used with the `python-static` port, which will build using the modules that have previously been built.  This will then assemble a unified static library that will be linked into the `.pexe` for python.  You shouldn't need to copy any module components by hand.

Comment: Is there something specific I need to do to get `python-static` to build (beyond installing the SDK and dependencies)? It's failing with the error message `libppapi_simple_cpp.a: error: undefined reference to 'PSUserMainGet'`.